# Trigonometry + Geometry

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

In the given triangle we have this point $O$ such that $\angle OAB=\angle OBC=\angle OCA=\omega$ Hence prove that $\cot\omega=\cot A+\cot B+\cot C$.

I figured out the RHS by using sine and cosine identities but the LHS couldn't be worked out by me. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are dealing with the [Brocard angle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrocardAngle.html). Notice that, by the [trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml),

$$ \sin(\omega)^3 = \sin(A-\omega)\sin(B-\omega)\sin(C-\omega). \tag{1}$$
Use the sine addition formulas to write the RHS of $(1)$ as a sum of sines, then write $\sin(A)$ as $\frac{2\Delta}{bc}$ and $\cos(A)$ as $\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$. Do the same for $B$ and $C$ and that will lead to:
$$ \cot(\omega) = \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{4\Delta}=\cot(A)+\cot(B)+\cot(C).\tag{2} $$

You may prove the same by proving first that the trilinear coordinates of the [Brocard points](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrocardPoints.html) are
$$\left[\frac{b}{c};\frac{c}{a};\frac{a}{b}\right]\quad\text{and}\quad \left[\frac{c}{b};\frac{a}{c};\frac{b}{a}\right]. \tag{3}$$